# Assembly of the Isoparametric Quadratic load vector in Matlab

Tags: finite-element, pde, matlab

I work to solve  PDE using FEM in the case P2 on Matlab. I try to correctly assemble load vector using quadratic Lagrange shape functions $$b_i =(f,\phi_i)=\sum_{q=1}^{nq}f(r_q,s_q)*\phi_{i}(r_q,s_q)*w_q*det(J(r_q,s_q)).$$
Here is what I did

```
[rspts,qwgts] = Gausspoints(precision); % quadrature rule
np      = size(p,2);                   % number of nodes
nt      = size(t,2);                   % number of elements

b = sparse(np,1);

for i=1:nt % loop over elements

nodes = t(1:6,i); % node numbers
x = p(1,nodes);   % node x-coordinates
y = p(2,nodes);   % node y-coordinates

bK=zeros(6,1); % elements load vector

for q=1:length(qwgts)                                  % quadrature loop   
r=rspts(q,1);                                         % quadrature r-coordinate
s=rspts(q,2);                                         % quadrature s-coordinate
[S,dSdx,dSdy,detJ]=Isopmap(x,y,r,s,@P2shapes);        % map

wxarea=qwgts(q)*detJ/2;                               % weight times area

bK=bK+S*f(mean(r),mean(s))*wxarea; % elements load vector
end
b(nodes)       = b(nodes) +bK;
end
```

**My problem...**
When I take PDE with source term f=0, the Plot of Numerical solution and exact solution gives the same result. Howerver if I put for example f(x,y)=x+y, I end with a plot difference between the two solutions.

**Brief explanation**
I have found helpful information: [Computation of stiffness matrix with variable coefficient](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/27420/computation-of-stiffness-matrix-with-variable-coefficient)

**SOLUTION:**
It comes that I didn't understand properly the logic of the mapping (x,y) domain to (r,s) domain. The integral can be written like this: (exactly in the line of elements load vector )

```
 ...

x_physical= dot(x,S);
y_physical= dot(y,S);
bK=bK+S*f(x_physical,y_physical)'*wxarea;
...
```

Comment: You haven't included a question mark (?) in your question; this makes it harder to know what you are asking.

Comment: @Richard, my question is : How to compute of load vector in Matlab for solving PDE using FEM in the case P2 ? There is the same topic for stiffness matrix in Python, pls see https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/27420/computation-of-stiffness-matrix-with-variable-coefficient

Answer (score 0):

I see where the thing fails. This problem has already been asked and answered before, see in [Computation of stiffness matrix with variable coefficient](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/27420/computation-of-stiffness-matrix-with-variable-coefficient).

I edited my question, problem solved. Thank you, it was a bit stupid, but as we say, the devil is in the details.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).